# How to check if the first character of a string is uppercase?

Tags: c++, string, char, uppercase

I have a function which takes a string as an argument.
What I want to do is check if the string starts with an upper case letter. If this is true, then I want to return true. If it does not start with an upper case letter then I wish to return false. Simple enough?

The code I was using is this:

```
bool filter(string word)
    {
        char cWord[50];
        char c;
        for(int i = 0; i <= word.size(); i++)
        {
            cWord[i] = word[i];
        }
        c = cWord[0];
        if(isupper(c)){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }
```

However I don't think it functions how I would like it to. Can anyone confirm that my function should work correctly, or whether there is a better way to check if the first character is a capital letter?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Just be aware that isupper takes into account the system locale to decide wether the char it receives is an upper case letter or not.

Comment: Why did you copy the string? I assume `string` is `std::string` and `isupper` is `std::isupper`?

Comment: Also, you are vulnerable to buffer overflows... What happens if word is 50 characters or more?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be as simple as this:

```
bool firstUpper(const string& word) { return word.size() && std::isupper(word[0]); }
```

Comment: This, but also think about what you want for empty string.

Comment: I think `!word.empty()` or `word.size() > 0` would be less confusing than `word.size()`. You should probably also use `std::isupper`.

Comment: For me `word.size()` is not confusing and it shouldn't really be for any competent C++ programmer. OK for `std::isupper`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `std::isupper` from the header `<cctype>`, after checking that the string isn't empty.

```
bool filter(const std::string& word)
{
  return (!word.empty()) && std::isupper(word[0]);
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well that's the question isn't it! Nobody's answered it yet, mainly because we don't know what the question is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I should stop assuming that the title of a question carries any relevance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your function works as long as your argument `word` is shorter than 50 characters. If `word` is longer, you will overwrite `cWord` and corrupt your stack. As others already have shown, there is no need to copy `word` for testing the first character.